# Split string with numbers and letters in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field on a SQL Server data base that contains numbers and letters like this:

Name surname1 surname2 3333 1T NP

The field is nchar data type

I need extract name surname1 and surname2 in a field, and the 3333 in other field for a report.

I used this code

```
Whileprintingrecords;
stringvar array Names := split({Table.Field}," ");

If ubound(Names) >=3 then
Names [1] + " " +Names [2] +" " + Names [3];
```

But only works with names and surname like "name surname1 surname2"

The problem is that the name can be "Jose Luis" and surname 1 or surname2 "De La Bella"

How can split the field when find a number?

Thanks!!

Comment: this might help https://kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/51212

Comment: If your last two field doesnt have space in their Characters, count from end to that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data field is consistent & you can guarantee the last three indices are reserved...
Just concatenate the indices that you know will be part of name, surname1, & surname2 (e.g. up to the index of the digits)

```basic
WhilePrintingRecords;

Local StringVar Array Names := SPLIT({Table.Field}, " ");
Local StringVar Name := "";

Local NumberVar index := 0;
Local NumberVar limit := UBOUND(Names)-3;

For index := 1 To limit Do(
    Name := Name & Names[index] & IIF(index = limit, "", " ");
);

Name
```

Comment: That code throws a warning:
"Not too many parameters have been passed to this function"

Comment: Can you state which function it is throwing this error on please?

Comment: I can't. Crystal reports only throw that message and mark the `Next` at the end.

Comment: @Victor : Sorry about that- got a little mixed up with the language.  I've updated the `For` loop with proper syntax.  The `Do` statement was missing, there is no `Next` keyword which ends the block in Crystal.

Comment: Ok now didnt throw Warning. But now only return TRUE or  FALSE. How can I print the value instead TRUE or FALSE. Thx very much for your help.

Comment: @Victor Ah, no problem.  Just include the `StringVar` at the end of the formula w/ no semi-colon such that Crystal knows what data it should return/format.  I've added what I mean to the code in the answer.

Comment: @Victor : Glad I could help- welcome to `StackOverflow`, enjoy your stay.